# HTML-PHP: background image not showing

Tags: php, html

I have tried to add an image in a table cell as background image with the code below, but it is not working properly.

```
<tr><td style="background-image:url('search_images/Zyra.png')">Zyra</td></tr>
```

I've tried with different quotes and without the `url()` but in all cases only the text shows.

EDIT:  Going to post my php code.

```
  echo "<td style='width:100%; background-image: url(search_images/".$row["champion"].".png)'>".$row["champion"]."</td>";
```

This works in that it shows the images with the text over them except it shows just a single row and the cell size is fit to the text instead of the background image.

I want the rows to fill the width of the browser window and the cells to be the size of the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, check your browser console for errors, if it says the image is not found then you might be mistyping the image path.

If the image and the HTML file being served are in the same directory you can use `background-image:url('./image.jpg');`, otherwise a full path is needed starting from the HTML page's directory like `background-image: url('./firstDir/secondDir/image.jpg');`.

Here is a working example of your code working:

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td style="height:80px; width:100px; line-height:70px; background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJbUiuUbKuYmKJfS4dYY0XGtRCGmNTco916Tyfiuf84wkhuWSj); background-size: 100% 100%; color:#F00; font-weight:bold;">This is test</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The thing is I'm using a PHP loop to create a table of 149 cells.  This will add 149 lines to my HTML.  Surely there is a better way?

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. You are most likely having trouble with the image path.

Comment: Okay, this works as in it shows the image.  But the cell is not the same size as the image.  And all the cells are in one row; I want the number of cells per row to be determined by the width of the browser window.  Could you help me with this also?

Comment: Sure, do you know the browser width beforehand? To clarify, PHP is server side languauge and the server doesn't care about your resolution or screen width. That's the browser's problem. But if you sent a variable `cell.php?width=1024` to the PHP program, then the program would know your current browser width and then you could easily restrict a for loop to write `browserWidth/pictureWidth` number of cells per row.

Comment: I edited my answer so the background image covers the entire cell.

Comment: But that wouldn't work if I resize the browser.  Maybe there's no solution to my problem.  I'm going to try using image tags inside <td></td> and find a way to draw text over the image.

Comment: Thanks for making bg image fit to cell but I actually want it the other way around.

Comment: Ok, I made it the other way around. Now you specify the height and width and the image stretches to fill the background. And to solve your problem with the cell count per row you could use AJAX to call the PHP file to give you already prepared cells (with background image and similar already specified) and then make the calculations and table later (after you receive the cells by AJAX call) with JavaScript. You could also easily detect `browser resize` with jQuery and put in a few `if` statements to delete the table if necessary and draw a new one from `old` AJAX data.

Comment: My current solution is just `<td><a href="champion.php?champ=Aatrox"><img src="search_images/Aatrox.png"></a></td>` Line after line just like that, without a `<table>` or `<th>` or `<tr>` tag.  The cells fit the window perfectly, even while resizing the window.  However I'm unable to get text INSIDE the images.

Comment: Ok, well then this is a better idea: Instead of `<td>` without proper `<table>` and `<tr>` tags, try making each picture be inside a `<div>` so then you could specify each div's `height` and `width` and set `position:relative;` and `float:left;`. Then add the picture inside the div. If you enter the image as a background image then you just enter the text in the div. If you enter the image as `<img>` tag  then make a `<div>` for the text and insert it into the first div and use this on the text div -> `position:absolute` and `top:20px`, `left:3%` or similar to adjust the position.

Comment: If all the divs have the same fixed height the `position:relative` and `float:left` will make the divs fill out the background. If they don't have the same fixed height you might find gaps where you are expecting an element.  Finally you can add `margin-left:10px;` to move them away from each other. This solution will work  when resizing (the divs will rearrange) the browser window.

Comment: [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/3zep1hhm/) is a working fiddle. It does **exactly** what you want correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are putting `<table>` tags around your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags (this is what makes the snippet work). You can also add a width and height to the  if you'd like to show more of the image.

```css
td.bg{
  background-image:url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png')
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="bg">Zyra</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. My guess is that because you are using a `png` file, which may generate **white background** for those `blank pixels`. 
Below is an example, showing it works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np80G.jpg?s=48&g=1'); 
background-size: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; 
color: white; font-weight: bold; padding: 20px;">              
                some text here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm using a PHP loop to make my cells.  I added this to the edit.  But whenever it makes them it makes the size of the cell depend on the text.  How can I make it depend on the size of the image?

Comment: @JuanBiche try adding `background-size: auto; background-repeat:no-repeat;`